# How to Enter text in rich text editor in selenium webdriver?

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver, textarea

We have a rich text editor in our application which we are automating using selenium . Below is the html for the same .

```
<iframe style="height: 76px; width: 1004px;"></iframe>
<html><head></head><body spellcheck="false"></body></html>
<head></head>
<body spellcheck="false"></body>
<html><head></head><body spellcheck="false"></body></html>
<iframe style="height: 76px; width: 1004px;"></iframe>
<div class=""><iframe style="height: 76px; width: 1004px;"></iframe></div>
<textarea class="form-control Editor" name="actionUpdate" id="actionUpdateId" style="display: none;"></textarea>
```

I have tried multiple options . Following code works perfectly fine on chrome browser

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
WebElement el  =  driver.switchTo().activeElement();
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(el).perform();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body")).sendKeys("Check");
```

However it does not work on IE11 browser as it is unable to find element using xpath. 
The difference between both the browsers is when I type something in text field using IE it goes to textarea tag. However in chrome it types in body tag . I have tried finding element using ID= "actionUpdateID" in IE but it throws an exception saying Element not displayed, maybe because of style = "display : none;"

Comment: Is that really the full `XPath`?  That doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Yes thats the full xpath, As i am switching to iframe maybe that's why it is working fine just with /html/body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since manually entering text in your application goes into the **textarea** element, you can try to set value using *sendKeys* to *textarea* element in selenium.
When you set some value in *textarea* element using *selenium*, the same value will be added to the *rich text editor* in the web application.

But as per your HTML code the *textarea* element is styled as **display:none** due to which your *selenium* code will throw an *Exception* when you *sendKeys* to the element. This can be fixed if the *display* attribute is changed to *inline* or *block*.

Thus, you first need to set style of *textarea* to **display:inline** and then set some value to the element using *sendKeys*.

To change style of ***textarea*** element using ***JavascriptExecutor*** :

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementsByName('actionUpdate')[0].style.display='inline'");
```

To set some value to your ***rich text editor***, use the below code :

```
driver.findElement(By.name("actionUpdate")).sendKeys("Show this message in rich text editor");
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScriptExecutor is better way to handle rich text boxes. Just switch to proper iframe and set innerHtml to body of that iframe.

`WebElement text= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
(JavascriptExecutor)driver.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = 'Set text using innerHTML'", text);`

Comment: unable to find element with css selector == body

Answer (score 0):

Thank Himanshi
I solved this issue by your approach. Here's my code.

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('description')[0].style.display='inline'")
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('description')[0].style.visibility='visible'")
```